# How would I add a calendar to only one page in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Note: I'm pretty new to Orchard.

I was wondering what steps do I need to take add a calendar that has the functionality to save users' vacation days and business trip days. I only need this calendar and functionality on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is pretty broad. First, I don't think there are any existing Calendar modules for Orchard (yet), so you will need to create a custom module to house your calendar functionality. To learn how to do that, you can read the [Orchard Documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/). Check the sections related to creating modules, and creating custom Content parts.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I was looking for general steps and needed a point in the right direction.

Comment: This answer should get you started then. (Accept/vote if so :)